# File mkdirs() not working as expected

Tags: java

I am currently trying to test if a directory exists and if it does not I want the program to create the full directory specified in `reportPath`.  When I run the code, `mkdirs()` returns false and the directory specified in `reportPath` is not created.  Doesn't `mkdirs()` make the entire path if it doesn't exist?

Currently working with the below code:

```
String reportPath = outputFile+"\\"+providerName+"\\"+testMode+"\\";//+testTarget+"\\";
File dir = new File(reportPath);

if (!dir.exists()) {
    System.out.println("Report Directory does not exist");
    System.out.println("Directory created:" + dir.mkdirs());
}

PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(reportPath+fileName, "UTF-8");
int id = 1;
writer.println("ID,Provider,Key Type,Key Size,Operation,Parameters,Data Size,Passed,Error details");

for (TestResult r : results) {
    writer.println(Integer.toString(id) + "," + r.provider + "," + r.keyType + "," + r.keySize + "," + r.operation + "," + r.parameter + "," + r.dataSize + "," + r.passed  + "," + r.errorDetails);
        id++;
}
writer.close();
```

When I run it, I get the following error:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: <path> (Access is denied)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
(followed by a long list of errors)
```

Comment: you has not permission to create directory in "dir" path

Comment: See answer, permissions seem good.  Looked into that before posting

Comment: Note that a `FileNotFoundException` was not really the most "speciifc" exception. Can you print the `reportPath` to see what it looks like.

Comment: Did your code print `Directory created:false` ?

Comment: Your `reportPath` starts with "outputFile" (`String reportPath = outputFile+"\\" ...`). That sounds suspiciously like the first level directory is something that is a file, which may already exist. You can't create a directory if a file by the same name already exists. Have you checked that?

Comment: outputFile is equal to  \\tsclient\Remote_Computer\ReportFolder\.  @ErwinBolwidt yes it did.

Answer (score 2):

You say:

> permissions seem good

Appearances can be deceptive!

The "Access is denied" is happening because the operating system won't let you either access / create / write to a file or directory.  You can assume that it is only doing this because *something* about your request violates the access control rules.

Here are some of the possibilities.

1. The path you are using may referring to some other file or directory than what you think; e.g. it may be a relative path and the current directory is not what you think, or there might be a error in the pathname (spelling, case-sensitivity, etc)
2. The application may not be running as the correct user.  Or on Windows, it may not have administrator privilege (if that is required).  Or the user many not be in the correct group (on UNIX/Linux ...)
3. The permissions may not what you think.  Have you checked the group permissions?  Have you checked for ACLs?   Did you check all directories in the path ... starting from the file system root?
4. On Linux, this could be something to do with SELinux, or AppArmor, or running in a Docker container, or something like that.
5. If you are trying to create a directory on a locally mounted remote file system, it could be due to a mismatch between local and remote identity system.
6. If you are trying to use GPFS / AFM caches, NFS identity mapping, etcetera .....

---

Summary:  *something* is wrong with the permissions / access control, and that is where the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

java.io.File is old and obsolete.  Use the [java.nio.file package](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/nio/file/package-summary.html) instead:

```
Path dir = Paths.get(outputFile, providerName, testMode);
Files.createDirectories(dir);

PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(Files.newBufferedWriter(dir.resolve(fileName)));
```

Most methods of java.io.File just return a boolean, without telling you what went wrong.  Methods of `Files` always succeed if they return;  if they fail, they throw an informative and useful exception.

Comment: Exception saving file java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: is what i get from it

Comment: @PUG Look at the exception’s stack trace.  Which method threw that exception?